# I want discard those unique ID where tag value = 2 ,3. so the answer should be only b,d,c

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

[image]

so here unique ID list and tag is there.
i want only those rows which does not include tag = 2, 3.
so answer should be unique ID = b,d,c

unique ID 
tag

Comment: that table you created, copy it and paste it as text into the question, also include your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firt filter `Unique_id` with matched `2,3` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then filter non matched `Unique_id` with  [`np.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
mask1 = df['tag'].isin([2,3])

out = np.setdiff1d(df['Unique_id'].unique(), df.loc[mask1, 'Unique_id'].unique()).tolist()
print (out)
['b', 'c', 'd']
```